# Permission Sets: Setting multiple values

Tags: permission-sets

We have a requirement to create a Permission Set to give View All permission on most, but not all, standard and custom objects.  This is easy to do with the non enhanced Profile UI, but takes a huge amount of time with the Permission Set enhanced UI. We have to click into the object setting, then click on Edit, then check the setting, and click Save, and then repeat for all objects.  Is there a way of being able to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Maybe using and ide to modify metadata for the perm set if u know how to

Comment: so why not just revert to the old UI for this task then undo?

Comment: the old UI is not available for Permission Sets